# Jmeter - proxy errors - connection time out

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to run a simple test with 50 users. The tests runs fine without any errors when 20 users but start throwing errors when i do run it with 50. 
Error i get is:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connect to .....failed: Connection timed out: connect
(Also we have the same tests recorded in Visual studio and it works fine without any proxy errors)

There is another error that comes when i increase the user from 20 to 50 is Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException/Non HTTP response message: Read timed out(which is not coming with Visual Studio performance run)

I have tried to increase the connection timeout to 60000 as per some threads i did read before , still no help.

Any ideas what can i try.(Comparison with Visual Studio is done as we are planning to move everything to Jmeter from Visual Studio that we currently use)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you're getting these timeouts because the application you're testing gets overloaded.

Not knowing the details of your Visual Studio and JMeter load test it's hard to say what is the exact reason, most probably it's connected with [think times](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/edit-think-times-in-load-test-scenarios?view=vs-2019). When you record your test in Visual Studio it automatically adds think times based on delay between actions in browser and by default JMeter doesn't record the think times.

So my expectation is that you need to add relevant [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/) to slow down JMeter throughput to the Visual Studio one. Another option is using `Recording with Think Time` template

[image]

More information: [Jmeter | Capture Real Think Time of User](https://medium.com/@priyank.it/jmeter-capture-real-think-time-of-user-832a3e00e87a)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri , i tried with recording with Think time and added timers accordingly and could get rid of the Read Timeout errors. But i am unable to run a test beyond 50 users as when i go beyond 50 to even 60 i start getting lot of proxy errors(that we don't get in Visual studio). have already raised this with out Network team but just wondering if its anything related to JMeter settings.

Comment: It was internal network issue for the threads and is resolved now.